# Some commands from system menu of panels dissappeared

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, menu

When I right click with mouse on the Panel in the system menu I don't see all the commands that were before.

For example, when I click on the Panel I see only two commands: (1) Help and (2) About the panel. On the applets also there are some commands dissappeared.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by running following command in the terminal and logging out 
from the system

> rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/panel

However I have lost my data of the panel. So, be carefull if you want to use this command.

Answer (score 1):

This is as a result of [moving to application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10092/why-do-indicator-applets-exist), there is no longer a seperate left/right click for items, just left click.

Comment: I think it doesn't answer to my question, at least doesn't solve.

Comment: Can you perhaps add more detail to your question? A screenshot perhaps?