# Cannot double click Indicators (notify bar) to launch some applications or open their main window

Tags: 11.10, indicator

I've recently updated to Oneiric.  I've noticed though that some of the indicators that are supposed to open a window when you double click it no longer works.  In fact you can only left click and or right click to open a menu.  You should to be able to double click the icon to open up the programs main window.  Now I can no longer access some of the stuff easily that I used to before.  Example KeePassX.

Normally when you run KeePassX it's hidden and minimized to the Indicator (notify bar).  You had to double click on it and type the unlock code to get the full window.  Now I can't even do that as the only options are the global unlock and exit from the menu that pops up.

There are other indicators that do the same thing.  The Skype indicator used to open the window when you double clicked it.  Now you have to select 'Activate" from the menu window.

I don't know why this was changed or is a bug.  I'm hoping there is a way to fix this problem as there are several indicators and applications I use that use indicators that no longer work now.  Again I only have access to their menu's but can no longer double-click.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have enabled some applications to use the older notification tray, as indicators are (by design) supposed to act like menus, so double clicking on them shouldn't work:

- [Why do indicator applets exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10092/why-do-indicator-applets-exist)
- [Indicator applet-less applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11349/indicator-applet-less-applications)

Comment: Is there anyway to enable the functionality of the older applications?  Seems sorta silly to me that I no longer properly use them with the change to the indicators.  It was working fine in 11.04.  Now I can't access some of the program main windows to even use them.  It seems to work if I switch to Gnome 3 shell and look at the notification bar on the bottom right.  I shouldn't have to be forced to do this though to be able to access my programs.  A lot of these old programs work perfectly fine and have been working fine for years.  Any help would be great. :)

Comment: Canonical insists in breaking backwards compatibility.

The fact that the older notification tray isn't the most usable doesn't mean it can be changed overnight without affecting users. Like @Xruptor mentions, some applications' behavior is broken without the ability to double click the icons since they were developed with the older tray's functionality in mind. There should at least be an option to go back.

Comment: The tray hasn't been changed "overnight", the API has been deprecated over the last 3 years (since 10.04), if the application hasn't been updated file a bug with them.